# Prevent hidden overflow of fixed element

Tags: html, css

I have a panel of content that is fixed to the bottom of the page. While this works fine on tall screens (where the viewport is taller than the panel's contents) on smaller viewport heights (e.g. mobile landscape) the panel disappears off the screen and since it is `position: fixed` you are not able to scroll the content (vertically).

HTML:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-content">
        <p>Panel contents</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.panel {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2em;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.panel .panel-content {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 30em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #fff;    
}
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/eW2b3/

How can I ensure that if the viewport is not big enough to fit the panel contents the user can at least scroll the panel contents? I'd prefer a CSS only approach but JavaScript is an option.

Note that the height of the panel is variable.

Comment: You could change the position from fixed to absolute or relative when the viewport height is smaller than 400px with media queries

Comment: I don't understand the reason for adding `100%` as `min-height`?

Comment: @srekoble unfortunately I do not know the height of the panel as it contains user defined content.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan - you're right, the min-height is irrelevant. I've removed it from the post.

Answer (score 0):

You already set max-width for panel and .panel-content.  Why not setting up `min-width` and `min-height` inorder to enable the overflow.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eW2b3/9/)

Comment: That does not resolve the issue. If you resize the browser viewport to smaller than the panel, the content is cut off and you don't get any scrollbars.

Comment: @BenFoster Actually when I reduce the browser horizontally (x-axis) I am getting scrollbar but not for y-axis since there is no height assigned for .panel

Comment: I need to be able to scroll the content vertically if the viewport *height* is smaller than that of the panel.

Comment: @BenFoster setting up a height could solve http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/DrE6m/1/ but needs some shape

Comment: Yes, but the panel is no longer fixed to the bottom of the page in your example.